# retrieve equal value from mysql

Tags: python, mysql

In my code, when the `raw_input` is equal, it must print the respective single value, but here I get both the values.

If I type `raw_input` is bike, it displays both bike and car, instead of only bike

Please help, me to get only the one value

Database:

```
bike
car
```

coding:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT A1 FROM adarsh1")

name = raw_input("What's your name? ")
keywords1=[]
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords1.append(i[0])

    if name in keywords1:
        print i[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords1.append(i[0])
    if name == i[0]:
        print i[0]
    # Do whatever other things are being done in this loop
```

The condition on which you were outputing the database value in your posted code (checking if `name` is in `keywords1`) will cause that `print` statement to run for every database value inclusively after the one that matched the user's input.  From your question, you only want the `print` statement to execute once, and never again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like problem with your indentation. Your if condition should be outside your for loop. (So when inside the for loop, IF condition check will happen for n number of time where n equals to number of rows in your table).

But why complicating this code. You can easily achieve this using your sql query itself.

```
name = raw_input("What's your name? ")
cursor.execute("SELECT A1 FROM adarsh1 where A1 = '%s'"%name)
cursor.fetchall() # will have your filtered result.
```